Roadmap for self study in philosophy
I am new to philosophy and want to systematically study it on my own. I have been introduced to Oriental philosophy, including the Vedas, Upanishads, Advaita, Buddhism, Jainism, and Sikhism, as a result of my culture and traditions, whereas my exposure to Western philosophy is more limited; just some names and a little information about them. What would be a proper roadmap for me to enter into Western philosophy: what sequence to follow, what important ideas and terminologies to understand beforehand, and what differences in learning approach between Eastern and Western philosophy should I know about?

Start with Will Durant. Its a pleasant read. Then come here and ask more pointed questions. Some other material in here and here

What about reading some Neitzsche!  It is always entertaining, compact, and controversial.  Knock yourself out.

Some say philosophy is exactly the quest for personal meaning. "I have an answer, do you have the question?"

History is important.
Where do our ideas come from? Who first formulated them? How did they develop? What is or was the social and cultural context?
Bertrand Russell gave us this marvelous metaphor:

Language is shot through with the faded hues of past philosophical theories.

For Western philosophy, in particular Greek philosophy, Bertrand Russell's A History of Western Philosophy is an excellent introduction. Russell (1872-1970), as you may know, was an important mathematician and philosopher, one of the founders of the modern analytic tradition. He is an excellent teacher. His prose and style are very clear and accessible.
For Chinese philosophy, I recommend, Fung Yu-lan and Derek Bodde's, A History of Chinese Philosophy, Vol 1. which covers the classical, formative period of Chinese philosophy, up to about 100 BC. (There is also an abridged version of this book, A Short History of Chinese Philosophy.)
If you want to get a better picture by also looking at some actual texts (even if only in translation), then Wing-Tsit Chan, A Source Book in Chinese Philosophy is very good. It gives short summaries of the main questions and ideas in the various philosophical schools, but the bulk consists of translations of core texts. As to actual sources, you could take a look at the Tao Te Ching, which is very short and may have even more translations than the Bible (Ursula K. Le Guin and J. P. Seaton's translation is very good; it preserves the poetry) and the Analects (the old Legge translation is a bit stuffy but really not bad).
If you're interested in history of philosophy and in cross-cultural comparisons then it's also instructive to see how different cultures first meet and how cultural artifacts (texts) were received or appropriated (with all the struggles of translation and interpretation). A very nice detail study of how the Confucian Analects (the main text in Confucianism containing short dialogues and sayings of Confucius and his students) were first received in Europe is Constructing Confucius in the Low Countries by two Dutch scholars, Trude Dijkstra and Thijs Weststeijn.
Logic/methodology of science/the art of argumentation
My own first introduction to the scientific study of logic was as a math freshman in a course about "Logic and Set Theory". But that may be somewhat limiting in a philosophical context. It may be better to look at a broader, less formal, more pragmatic context: How do people actually debate and how can we advance civil, objective public debate? Arne Naess focusses on that question in his book Communication and Argument which imo should be compulsory reading in any philosophy curriculum. Naess is refreshing to read since he asks for and allows for a lot more empirical study in philosophy. He is also refreshing since he is not locked up in the ivory tower of abstruse, purely academic discussions (like: "Is a hole in a sock an  abstract object or a concrete object? Are we justified in saying the hole exists?") At the end of his life Naess became involved in the current ecological movement - both as philosopher and as activist. See for instance: Deep Ecology and Education: A Conversation with Arne Naess
Ethics
In ethics, I believe it's important to not just study philosophers, but at least study the essentials of (mathematical) game-theory and (socio-) biology. Ken Binmore's Natural Justice is a very good introduction in this field.
Ethology is also important. Both the Western and Chinese philosophical traditions are strongly anthropocentric. Anthropocentric biases can result in absurd opinions (and abusive behavior towards other animals). Current ethological studies can counter-act this and make us more aware of those deep biases. Frans de Waal's Good Natured (or any of his other studies) is a nice introduction to this field.

You have my +1. Just some comments. You mention Chinese but not Indian, Islamic? See my contrast of Parochial vs Canonical

I've taken the liberty to format more suitably for what works here. Please accept/modify as you see fit

@Rushi - Indian philosophy has a rich, important tradition. I didn't mention it mainly because the OP wrote that they are already familiar with those traditions.
Also, in this context, Western includes Islamic. Indian traditions are less anthropocentric, perhaps, then all the others. The concerns about parochial vs canonical that you bring up are really important, I agree, and often ignored/shrugged off in Western academic philosophy. (Historians and filologists don't ignore them, though.)

I don't know in what sense Chinese, especially Taoism is anthropocentric. Confucius maybe... My sense is throughout the east, prani—breathing creature, and jiva — soul are synonymous, whether it's Hindu, Buddhist, Jain, Sikh... Yeah Buddhists will say soul is no-soul — anatta. But this is a technicality

Taoism is perhaps not very anthropocentric, or perhaps not at all - depending on your definition. But Confucianism is very much so - whatever sensible definition you give. When I was speaking about "Chinese philosophy" I was generalizing, and mostly thinking of Confucianism. -- "People generalize too much", as a friend of me once said.

Yeah... I guess for an actual Chinese statistically it's likely to be Confucianism whereas for the rest of the world "Chinese" more likely means Taoism

If you want a (albeit a bit shallow) road map you could start with the History of Philosophy Without any Gaps podcast. It's a pretty extensive explanation of Western philosophers and traditions, and has some great entry points into texts or topics that may interest you.

Exactly! Freedom to dive into topics that seem the most relevant/interesting, and there's a lot of emphasis particularly important parts of the history.

I would start with Descartes' meditation and start with ontology and metaphysics and go on from there. I suggest Descartes because you already have read books that seem to be metaphysically and theologically focused and I believe this will be a good introduction to the almost "opposite" side of philosophy. You can find a lot of things philosophy in the SEP (Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy)
You can also start with the classics like Plato and Aristotle, if you don't think that their writings are not too rough or disorganized.

@abracadabra I started out with Aristotle as a beginner and I must say I wouldn't have preferred any other way. Aristotle is actually one of the best and my one of my favorite philosophers.

Nobody reasonable and familiar with the material would argue Socrates (forms, cave, the good) or Aristotle (the categories) But Descartes?! No. No! No!! He's so bad because he's so good. IOW convincing.. Starting beginners on Descartes is like giving porn to children as literature. Once the solipsism bug gets in it doesn't get out easily.

@Rushi I find your comment rather hilarious and absolutely true but I would like to say this I started out with Descartes in introductory college philosophy and yes I did end up with a good dose of solipsism but funnily enough it was Descartes' philosophy that dug me out of that same hole. Surface level understanding of Descartes' philosophy = bad, but more understanding = ultimately good.

@Howwhye As I said (other answers) I dont know Descartes personally. Inter alia I mention: I read a book o coordinate geometry in school and was struck by the cleanliness n beauty compared to the traditional messy method. So he certainly has other areas of greatness. He more likely than not was a good man. The thing is that today the dangers of Descartes unleashed are much more acute than in his time and context. He: a christian in an unambiguously christian world, remained a christian. That forms an undergirding to everything of that time.

Today the default is secularism which is a strong but nonobvious form of relativism. Modern secularism + cartesian solipsism are a lethal combo. Having seen saints who could read other people's minds as easily as you read a book I am immune to the assumptions that lead inexorably to cartesian methodological doubt and thence solipsism. But most are not so fortunate. Hence the warning

(For western philosophy)
I would say Great Books of the Western World (from Encyclopedia Britannica) contains many classic texts enough to keep you thinking for a while.
The A Syntopicon: An Index to The Great Ideas (from Encyclopedia Britannica, compiled by Mortimer J. Adler) is a topical reference for the great ideas/topics philosophers talk about, and still relevant today. Each great idea is accompanied with a summary essay, which are a joy to read in their own right.
The "Great Ideas" tv program archives at American Archive of Public Broadcasting is a terrific source to arouse interest in philosophy. They are also by Mortimer J. Adler.
The Story of Philosophy by Will Durant is another classic book fit to be your first philosophy book.
Once you consumed all I mentioned, you would be well-prepared to read other philosophical works. Don't get lost in the minute details, and keep a holistic view and feel of Philosophy!

Road map to self-study in philosophy
Well, welcome to the club!
I will offer the same advice as I give to all newcomers who have the same question:read The Story of Philosophy by Will Durant. Published in 1926, the book has held up very well despite the passage of a century. Durant’s writing remains accessible. (So I second the very good recommendation of hym3242)
See you soon in these pages!
